# Is there a general code for the worksheet which I am current using?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a macro for analyzing a datalog. The datalog is generated from a hardware with a .txt file named AAA (while this might be changed automatically).
I have finished the macro and tested with this AAA file.
Is there any general code for AAA that I can alternate with?

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Desk"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='AAA'!$A$7:$A$20"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='AAA'!$C$7:$C$20"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Chair"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='AAA'!$A$629:$A$669"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='AAA'!$C$629:$C$669"
```

I would like to change AAA with the general code so I can penetrate this macro to every datalog instead of AAA only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- You can use a Variable instead of `AAA`, and assign a Value to that variable at the Beginning of the code.

**Like:**

```
nm = "AAA"

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Desk"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='" & nm & "'!$A$7:$A$20"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & nm & "'!$C$7:$C$20"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""Chair"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='" & nm & "'!$A$629:$A$669"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='" & nm & "'!$C$629:$C$669"
```

So you will have to change the Name once in line `nm = "AAA"`